# Make svg color scale fit the size of the parent div

Tags: reactjs, svg, legend

I have been using SVG to create the Discrete legend color selector. I want the color selector div to have fixed width and the content (svg cells)
should fit based on the width of the div. Note that since the code is long, i am just pasting few lines of code.

```
var cellWidth = 22;
var cellHeight = 22;
```

// this is not the full code

```
const selectedLegend = select(divRef.current);
selectedLegend
.append("div")
.append("svg")
.style("margin-top", "13px")
.style("margin-left", "137px")
.style("margin-right", "35px")
.style("width", "100%")
.style("height", "25px")
.style("background", "red")
```

// Code to fill the color

```
g.selectAll("g.legendCells")
.append("rect")
.attr("height", cellHeight)
.attr("width", cellWidth)
.style("fill", function (d: Record<string, unknown>) {
return d["color"];
```

// Alighment of cell in straight line

```
g.selectAll("g.legendCells")
.attr("transform", function(d: any, i: number) {
return "translate(" + (i * cellWidth) + ",0)" })
```

[image]

I want legend to take full width, it must cover whole background red color.

To be more precise, I want something like as shown below, the rect cells must fit the constant width.

[image]

Comment: Learn about the [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) and the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attributes and how they work together.

Comment: In the first code you write that a cell should be 22x22. Would this be the exact size in pixel or is it OK that the size of the cell increase/decrease when the div changes size?

Comment: The size of the cell (not the width of the div/svg) should increase/decrease and in general it should fill up the whole div/svg.  Also, I am new to the SVG and do not have much knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not setting a width on the svg and use the `viewBox` attribute the SVG will just fill the entire space.

### Update

The image should stretch: At all times the width should be 100% and the height should be fixed (here 50px). To make the image stretch you set the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute to "none".

```css
#container svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 2"
  width="100%" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect width="20" height="2" fill="#eee"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#000"/>
    <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#111"/>
    <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#222"/>
    <rect x="3" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#333"/>
    <rect x="4" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#444"/>
    <rect x="5" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#555"/>
    <rect x="6" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#666"/>
    <rect x="7" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#777"/>
    <rect x="8" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#888"/>
    <rect x="9" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#999"/>
    <rect x="10" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#aaa"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: but when I tried to add more cells to the svg as per your code snippet (https://jsfiddle.net/u48nt1j6/), it just increased the size of the width. I want the constant width and cells should fit inside it accordingly.

Comment: @coder91 I don't think that I understand you completely. In the above example I made space for 20 cell in a row, but I only added the first 10. The fist `<rect>` is just for marking the space - like you used a red color in you question. It is up to you to decide how many cells there should be in a row an adjust the viewbox accordingly.

Comment: The way I want is like suppose you gave as per your example row for 20 cells, even if u have 10 cells, then it should fill whole row and should not leave the space. Basically to say, the cells should fit inside the row , the width of the cell should adjust as per the row width and number of cells as shown in image above. For ex, if there are 5 cells and width of row is 5, then each cell should take width 1 and if there are 2 cells, then each cell should take width 2.5 each based on width of row

Comment: I assume that you have not understood my question. If you see this snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/ynbrmfh6/4/, it do not fill whole width (here color black). I am making color selector and different color legend has different number of cells
but size of the svg will be same for all and cells should fit within that. In general we cannot give fixed width for the cells as it need to change based on the width of the svg and number of cells within the svg. Suppose I have 10 svg, the width of all svg must be same but it can have varying number of cells.

Comment: @coder91 you need to adjust the viewBox to match the number of cell. In my example I have 10 cells, so the viewBox is "0 0 10 2". In your jsfiddle you have 13 cells, so "0 0 13 2"

Comment: Your solution works but I have one question to ask. Like I said earlier my SVG content varies so I cannot assign constant value to view box. Currently the way I am giving value is inside string literal something like svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 39 1"), where 39 must have changing value. I have length of cells which I am storing in variable say let cellLength = item.length. Issue is how can I assign cellLength in viewbox somthing like svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 cellLength 1") .

Comment: @coder91 something like this: `svg.attr("viewBox", \`0 0 ${cellLength} 1\`)`. Instead of normal quote marks (" or ') you use backticks (\`) and then the variable in `${...}` inside is.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs and solution :)

Comment: Do you know how can I add the label for each rect ? I am appending the text attribute to the rect and passing index as label but not sure where I am going wrong as the label are not shown